# How to insert into linq or lambda expression in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, lambda, linq-to-sql

How to this query convert to linq or lambda queries?

```
Student Table:

StudentClassID  StudentBranchId  BranchBookType NAME   SURNAME

1                   123             A           Alex    Martin

2                   124             B           John    Martin

1                   123             A           Kelvin  John

3                   124             C           Will    Suzzy

3                   124             C           Hary    Smith
```

If there are how many student ids in my first table, I want to insert into my second table according to those ids.
And if the value entered in the textbox is 1, I want to add 1 record to each id and 2 copies of each.

For example textbox value:1

I want to studentrecordtable:

```
StudentRecordTable:

StudentClassId   StudentBranchID BranchBookType BranchBookColor  BranchBookNumbers

1              123               A               Red                23

2              124               B               Red                23

3              125               C               Red                23
```

if textbox value is 2:

```
 StudentRecordTable:

StudentClassId StudentBranchID BranchBookType BranchBookColor  BranchBookNumbers

1              123               A               Red                23

1              123               A               Red                23/2

2              124               B               Red                23

2              124               B               Red                23/2

3              125               C               Red                23

3              125               C               Red                23/2
```

How to lambda expression or linq insert into studentrecord table:

**Insert Into values: StudentId,StudentBranchId,BranchBookType,Red,23**

Comment: `top 100 percent` is the entire dataset so you could skip it

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're asking. I don't see "this query", to begin with. Also, LINQ is a query language, it doesn't insert anything. And the description "add 1 record to each id and 2 copies of each" doesn't seem to match the first `StudentRecordTable` listing. Try to reword your question and show code of what you did so far. That usually clarifies a lot.